# Simple Javascript form validation code issue

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Basically I am trying to write some code to use for form validation, Im quite new to this but am managing ok I think? My issue is basically this, I have created 3 validation methods for the 3 inputs i have in my form but im not quite sure how i go about adding all 3 methods to the one button click?

my code so far is:

```
function validation() {
  function validateName() {
    console.log("reaching here");

    var name = document.getElementById("full_name");

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okName").className = "fail";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okName").className = "success";
    }
  }//End of validate name

  function validateEmail() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email");

    if (email.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okEmail").className = "fail";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okEmail").className = "success";
    }
  }//end of validate email

  function validatePhone() {
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone");

    if (phone.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okPhone").className = "fail";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okPhone").className = "success";
    }
  }//End of validate phone
}//End of validation function
```

I also tried removing all the validation methods from individual functions and just had them in one single fnction but this wouldnt work either? if anyone could shed some light on where im going wrong it would be great! Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to attach an `onclick()` event to your submit button - http://jsfiddle.net/zWrUM/

```
<button onclick="validation();">validate</button>

<script>
function validation() {
    var name = document.getElementById("full_name");
    if (name.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okName").className = "fail";
        alert("error 1");
        return false;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okName").className = "success";
    }

    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    if (email.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okEmail").className = "fail";
        alert("error 2");
        return false;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okEmail").className = "success";
    }

    var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    if (phone.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okPhone").className = "fail";
        alert("error 3");
        return false;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okPhone").className = "success";
    }

    alert("success")
}//End of validation function
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason this wont reach the second stage of the validation, it stops at alert 1? Having checked in the console to see if it was making it to the next step i can see it isnt even getting that far?

Comment: if you have an error in your 1st input it does `return false`, which stops the execution of the function

Comment: Ah ok i see it now! Thanks for your help!! Is there any way i can have it so all the checks are done at the same time?

Comment: Thats not exactly what im trying to do, you see I have 2 images that appear beside my inputs, one with a green tick for success and a red X for fail, so when I click submit as this code stops the process only the first red X appears if there is a mistake, is there a way I can have all 3 appear onClick of the submit or at least for however many invalid inputs there are?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and the oldIE similar methods.